# ssh client disconnected, after relogin, how can I recontrol my process or program?

Tags: ssh, gdb

as show below:

**Step 1:** SSH Login to remote host.

**Step 2:**  Use `gdb debug proc_a`.

**Step 3:** Use gdb subcommand `(gdb) shell vi tes.c`, edit the file.

**Step 4:** The ssh client have something unknown error failure link (can not input any command to remote host)

**Step 5:** I have to relogin the remote host using SSH.

The question is how can I continue to the debug work which the Step1f going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `screen`.

I would do: `screen gdb debug proc_a` at first.

When you need to reclaim it, call, `screen -r` for reattach.

Look for your `screen` instance which was running that cmd, and you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is how can I continue to the debug work which the step1 going?

Use `screen`. Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).